# Copying and pasting objects with the clipboard c#

Tags: c#, clipboard

Good morning,

I'm trying to copy an object with this method :

```
private void copierToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Clipboard.SetData("Tache", Tâche); //Tâche is an object of "Tâche"
}
```

And paste it with this one:

```
private void contextMenuStrip_option_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Clipboard.ContainsData("Tache"))
    {
        Tâche tache = (Tâche)Clipboard.GetData("Tache");

        contextMenuStrip_option.Items[3].Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        contextMenuStrip_option.Items[3].Enabled = false; // Disables the option to paste
    }
}
```

When nothing's in my clipboard, nothing happens and the **else{}** is executed.

Whereas when I copy, I have a error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast an object of type
>   'System.IO.MemoryStream' in type 'Task_Manager__Last_.Tâche'.

My class, however, is a serializer:

```
namespace Gestionnaire_de_tâche__Last_
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Tâche
    {
           //.....
    }
}
```

Do you have a solution?
Thank you

Comment: Can you show your `Tache` class. It seems what's in the clipboard is a memory stream which causes `(Tâche)Clipboard.GetData("Tache");` to fail

Comment: Also I think it will be fixed if you implement `ISerializable` in your `Tâche` class

Comment: What is inside the class? For a class to be serializable, all the data contained inside it need to be serializable as well.

Comment: Also... what's inside the MemoryStream? Might be interesting to at least read that into a byte array and check.